# What is the distribution of $Y_n=\ln\left(\text{ }1+\big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\big)^2\text{ }\right)$, where $\forall i: X_i \sim G({1\over2})$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given $\big(X_i\big)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ a series of independent random variables, $X_i \sim G({1\over2})$ (Geometric distribution) for all $i \ge 1$.

For $n \ge 2$, we mark the following:

$$\bar X_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i  \quad\quad\quad 
Y_n=\ln\big(1 + (\bar X_n)^2 \big)  \quad\quad\quad
T_n = (Y_n - \ln5)^2
$$

And we need to find the value $C_n$ and the distribution of $T$, which satisfies:

$$
\frac{1}{C_n} \sum_{n=1}^{12} T_n  \overset{d}{\to} T
$$

$$$$
Well, i'll save you the trouble. The final and correct answer is
$$C_n=\frac{32}{25n}, \quad T_n \sim \chi^2_{(12)} \text{  (chi distribution with 12 degrees of freedom)}$$

But i can't understand why. This is all I know so far:

Let $\big(Z_i\big)_{i=1}^{n}$ be a series of independent random variable with the same distribution $Z_i \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then we know that $\frac{Z_i - \mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$ for all $i$, and we know that the distribution of the following sum is:
$\sum_{i=1}^n  \big( \frac{Z_i-\mu}{\sigma} \big)^2 \sim \chi^2_{(n)}$.

My guess is that in my question:

$Z_i := Y_n = \ln\big(1 + (\bar X_n)^2 \big)$

$\mu := E(Y_n)  = \ln5$

$\sigma^2 := V(Z_i) = C_n$

and thus:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n  \big( \frac{Z_i-\mu}{\sigma} \big)^2  =  
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n  ( Z_i-\mu )^2}{{\sigma}^2} :=
\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{12} T_n}{C_n}   \overset{d}{\to} T
$$

But i can't understand how is that $E(Y_n)=\ln5$, or even what is the distribution of $Y_n$?

Am I on the right track? What are your thoughts about this question? How would you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the so called delta-method. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method. In this case,
$f(x) = \log(1+x^2)$ and since we have $\sqrt{n}*(\bar{X_n}-2)$ converges to $N(0,2)$,

$\sqrt{n}*(f(\bar{X_n}) -f(2))$ converges to $N(0, 2*(f'(2))^2)=N(0,32/25)$.

From this, $\frac{T_{n}}{C_{n}}$ converges to a chi-squared distribution.

Comment: Oh ok that's new for me. Thanks for the information!
You think there's another way to solve this or delta-method is the only way?

Comment: The sum of independent geometric random variables is distributed as the negative binomials and in principle you can find out the the distribution for each n. But that is going to be somewhat complicated. If you are interested only in the limit, I think delta-method is the right method to use in your context

Comment: thank you very much!